# Pressur change in a rigid tank with a constant volumetric flow rate leak

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I have a rigid tank with a volume of 4m^3. It is filled with a calorically perfect gas and has a leak with a constant volumetric flow rate of 300L/min. I need to find how long it will take for the pressure in the tank to reach 40% of the initial pressure assuming first isothermal and then isentropic processes. I assume that I will need to start with the continuity equation and the ideal gas law with calorically perfect assumptions. Maybe the energy equation would get involved. I’m struggling with where to start to set up the differential equation.

Comment: Welcome to physics SE. This look like a homework question - check https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic . You should show some progress you have made to be able to obtain some answer.

Comment: For the isothermal case, let n represent the number of moles remaining in the tank at time t.  What is the molar density of the gas?  What is the molar rate of discharge from the tank?  Based on the ideal gas law, what is the pressure?